# Different Page View for User

Tags: php, session

I want to try this. But I don't know that this will work or not and whether this is a good way for me to achieve what I want.

What I want is to show different page view for users (login and not login user)

I am going to use this method with session, but please check if I do it correctly:

```
<?php
session_start();

if ( $_SESSION['login_id'] == 0 || $_SESSION['login_id'] == '' ) {
    echo "user is not login, and I will show the not login page view to them";
} else {
    echo "user is login, and I will show the login page view to them";
}

require_once('configPDO.php');
?>
```

Comment: "But I don't know that this will work or not" --- what if you try it and come back with a real, not imaginary problem?

Comment: If you don't know if it'll work, try it..

Comment: If only you can tell me that the code above is correct, I will try this.

Comment: It's better if you try this code and check if it's ok, after if you have a problem, you can ask here for help :)

Comment: @Al Kush: are you seriously going to ask if every your line of code "is correct"?

Comment: Only on how I echo it.

Comment: You echo using `echo`

Comment: @Zerkms I mean how to put the all html tag there?

Comment: @AlKush Have you tried using Google yet..?

Comment: @Al Kush: `echo '<html><tag>';`

Comment: @zerkms Oke zerkms, I think the first problem is solved (how to echo the html tag). My seocnd question is, will it make the page to load down (to slow) because I echo two different page views?

Comment: @Al Kush: oh god... Forget about performance until you learn how to program. It's like asking how to perform a backflip on a bike when you cannot even ride straight on a flat surface.

Comment: Believe it or not, People use to call me "a miracle".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you stored the variable in $_SESSION in the right way, you can redirect the user in different pages using header after the login.

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['login_id']) && !empty($_SESSION['login_id'])){
   header("location:PAGELOGIN.php");
}
else{
   header("location:PAGENOTLOGIN.php");
}
?>
```

if you want to stay in the same page, you can do:

```
 <?php
    session_start();
    if(isset($_SESSION['login_id']) && !empty($_SESSION['login_id']))
   {
 ?> 
    YOUR HTML CODE
 <? 
  } else {
  ?> YOUR HTML CODE
 <?}
?>
```

this will show your html code using the php condition. tell me if this work ^^

Comment: The page is one, but only the view which is different.

Answer (score 0):

try this...

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['user'])){
   echo "iam login";
}
else{
   echo "not login";
}
?>
```